# .Net 7 - Is There a way to check if a custom middleware was added before another?

Tags: asp.net-core

As we are developing many apis in our company we want are developing a library that will share some common code between the application.

There's a middleware that we want to only be used before other middleware.

Is there a way to get the IApplicationBuilder middleware pipeline to check if the order is correct?

Comment: Custom [analyzer](https://blog.elmah.io/asp-net-core-middleware-with-roslyn-analyzers-part-1/) can help you.

Comment: Create an extension method to be used that maintaince the correct order of adding middlewares to the pipeline?

Comment: You're probably better off writing some integration tests to validate the correct behavior

Comment: For now I'm using a extension wrapper. But would be nice to make it work without it. 
I'll take a look at the analyzer @AlexanderPetrov sent